# Json Geocode address parsing in C#

Tags: c#, json, google-maps

I want to get address of the location
Iam using google geocode to get address by passing lat and long.

```
static readonly string RequestUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";

/// <summary>
        /// Gets the raw object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
protected JsonGeoData GetJsonObject() {

        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder( GeoRequest.RequestUrl);

        if (this.Location != null) {
            url.AppendFormat("latlng={0}", this.Location.ToString());
        }
        else {
            url.AppendFormat("address={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.Address));
        }
        url.AppendFormat("&sensor={0}", this.IsSensor.ToString().ToLower());
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Language))
            url.AppendFormat("&language={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.Language));
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Region))
            url.AppendFormat("&region={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.Region));

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return serializer.Deserialize<JsonGeoData>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }



      /// <summary>
        /// Gets the response.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public GeoResponse GetResponse() {
            return new GeoResponse(this.GetJsonObject());
        }

 /// <summary cref="A">
        /// fetching location from web
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        private string getloc(double plat, double plng)
        {
            try
            {    
                GeoRequest objreq = new GeoRequest(plat, plng);
                GeoResponse objres = objreq.GetResponse();
                if (objres.Results.Count > 0)
                { return objres.Results[0].FormattedAddress; }
                else
                { return "Unknown"; }
            }
            catch (FormatException) { return "Unknown"; }
            catch (Exception)
            { return "Unknown"; }
        }
```

iam trying to get json data from geocode and parse using serializer, 
But iam getting error 'sublocality_level_2 is not a valid value for GeoAddressType.'

Comment: Perhaps your `JsonGeoData` structure does not match that defined by the JSON

Comment: Does Geocode require something like 'Key' in order to use the service?